# Sound when timer stops swiftUI Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, timer, swiftui, apple-watch

I'm working currently on a timer app for the Apple Watch. I'm managed to get a sound when the timer reaches 5 seconds. Only, when I'm pressing "done" the timer sounds still plays and I don't now how to stop the sound. I'm using WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success).

I want to stop the sound when the "cancel" button is pressed within the 5 seconds and when the "done" button is pressed.

I cannot find anything on the internet. I think that WKInterfaceDevice does not have an stop function.

```
struct softView: View {

@State var timerVal = 10

var body: some View {

    VStack {

        if timerVal > 0 {
            Text("Time Remaining")
                .font(.system(size: 14))
            Text("\(timerVal)")
                .font(.system(size: 40))

                .onAppear(){
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                        if self.timerVal > 0 {
                            self.timerVal -= 1
                        }
                        if self.timerVal < 6 {
                            WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
                        }
                    }
            }
            Text("Seconds")
                .font(.system(size: 14))
            Divider()
            Spacer()

            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), label: {Text("Cancel")})
            //.cornerRadius(20)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)

            )



        }
        else {

            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), label: {Text("Done")})
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)

                )
        }

    }         .navigationBarHidden(true)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When does your `timer` know when to stop?
You have to define the event when the timer is to be stopped. That's where`.invalidate` will come handy.

#### Basic Example:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] (timer) in
  guard let _weakSelf = self else { timer.invalidate(); return }

  _weakSelf.timerVal -= 1

  if _weakSelf.timerVal < 0 { //if timer count goes negative then stop timer
    timer.invalidate()
  } else if _weakSelf.timerVal < 6 {
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
  }
}
```

---

For more control, i.e. If you want to stop the `timer` from, say, a button tap then we will have to make this `timer` object global.
Furthermore, if you want to pop the `View` after the `timer` is completed/cancelled then we need to make more changes.
This all gets a bit complicated but it's simple to understand.
I would suggest you to break out your timer related logic into an `ObservableObject` class and use it within your `View`.

#### Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var isShowingTimer: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationLink(destination: TimerView(isShowing: $isShowingTimer),
                     isActive: $isShowingTimer) {
                      Text("Start Timer")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `isShowingTimer` controls the push/pop event for `TimerView`

  - It is sent as a binding to `TimerView` so it can be updated from inside `TimerView` in order to pop.

---

```
struct TimerView: View {
  //Trigger for popping this view
  @Binding var isShowing: Bool

  @ObservedObject var timerControl = TimerControl()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("\(timerControl.count)")
        .onAppear(perform: {
          //start timer event
          self.timerControl.startTimer(from: 10)
        })
        .onDisappear(perform: {
          //stop timer if user taps on `Back` from the Navigation Bar
          self.timerControl.stopTimer()
        })
        .onReceive(timerControl.$isComplete, //observe timer completion trigger
                   perform: { (success) in
                    //hide this view
                    self.isShowing = !success
        })
        Text("Cancel")
          .onTapGesture(perform: {
            //stop timer event
            self.timerControl.stopTimer()
        })
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
class TimerControl: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count: Int = 0
  @Published var isComplete: Bool = false

  private var timer: Timer?

  init(){}

  func startTimer(from count: Int) {
    self.count = count

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] (timer) in
      guard let _weakSelf = self else { timer.invalidate(); return }

      print(_weakSelf.count)
      _weakSelf.count -= 1

      if _weakSelf.count <= 0 {
        _weakSelf.stopTimer()
      } else if _weakSelf.count < 6 {
        print(">>make some noise here<<")
      }
    }
  }

  func stopTimer() {
    guard isComplete == false else { return }
    timer?.invalidate()
    isComplete = true
  }
}
```

---

- `ObservableObject` class can emit changes
- `@Published` variables emit signals of change
- `@ObservedObject` listens for changes on the `ObservableObject`
- `.onReceive` handles `Publisher` events. In this case listens for changes by `timerControl.$isComplete`

Comment: One more (quick?) question. When I'm pressing Cancel or Done I want to go to the "original" view. But this line does network:NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), isActive:  $isTimerComplete, label: {Text("Done")}) Text("Cancel")

Comment: @Moi I dont quite follow. In this example when the timer completes, `NavigationLink` pushes another screen. Are you expecting to pop the timer view?

Comment: I'm gonna try to explain :-) I have a start view, from there I can select three timers (with different presets of seconds). That is the screen that the app starts. When I press one of those three buttons it will go to the "count down" screen. When you press "cancel" or "done" it should go back to the screen with the three options. That part works in my original code/post. I'm trying to adjust the NavigationLink with all kinds of options and replaced the destination with the ContentView() and added a Label. But it does not work.

Comment: @Moi To pop, we need to get the parent view to dismiss it. I have updated the answer with a possible solution. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Moi My pleasure :) Btw, I just updated the answer. Observe the `.onDisappear` part inside `TimerView`. In previous case if instead of `Cancel` you tapped on the navigation `Back`, the timer would continue to fire until it reached 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212593/discussion-between-moi-and-staticvoidman).